# Are external (for example Google products) javascript files cached by browsers?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache

Just curious about whether external, and specifically Google, javascript files are cached by users browsers and reusable across domains.

Let's say I have a website that uses Firebase and the Google Maps API:

```
// Firebase 4.6.0
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.0/firebase.js"></script>

// Google Maps javascript API 
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Now let's say user `A` visits my site, and he has recently visited another, unrelated, site that also happens to use Firebase 4.6.0 and the Google Maps javascript API - will his browser have cached those files already and use the cached versions of them? Or will "cross-domain" caching in this manner never happen?

Comment: Caching is literally the whole point of using a CDN.

Comment: Caching does depend only on the URI of the resource itself, not on the domain on which it is used.